# WebDriver - How to launch tests on remote server automatically?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, windows-server-2012

Problem:
To run WebDriver tests using it appears that the UI (desktop) must be active for WebDriver to 'see' the browser and correctly run the tests.

When trying to automatically launch a set of tests on a Windows 2012 server using Scheduled Tasks, the tests fail because when the tests are launched there is no UI/desktop active.

Bad solution:
The only way we can get the WebDriver tests to run properly is to *manually* log in to each Windows 2012 server that is hosting the tests so that the UI/desktop is active.  However, this is not practical if we are running tests on 20 servers at a time.  (We would need to have a human log into each server for each test run!)

Question:
How can we:

a) launch a Windows 2012 executable that gets an active UI/desktop (logged in) without a manual login?

b) get WebDriver to not need the UI/desktop to be active to run the test?

Comment: What browser are you trying to test against? IEdriver does not work as a remote service. Chrome and Firefox works fine though, I have my selenium hub running in Windows 10 via Task Scheduler, no login necessary.

Comment: We are using an older version of Firefox (28). Which is the pre gecko driver.  We couldn't figure out which version of the gecko driver to use with Hub.

When we tried to upgrade to the latest version of Selenium and related drivers it broke hundreds of our legacy tests.